# I am facing the issue of Unsupported version number [61.0] (maximum 57.0, Java 13) during a build in my ORACLE linux 7 how to resolve this?

Tags: proguard, oraclelinux, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am facing the issue of Unsupported version number [61.0] (maximum 57.0, Java 13) during a build in my Oracle Linux 7 on my local machine how to resolve this?

I tried looking into the new ones, but then it says the proguard file that I had updated has not been found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: You have classes compiled with Java 17 (class version 61), and either your Java, or your Proguard version only supports upto class version 57 (Java 13).

Comment: The above link doesnt help and like my proguard version is 6.2.2 i need a procedure of how to change it to the new one and wanna try that once too/.